# Use Enter Key to move to inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, enter

Is it possible to use the enter key to move to the next input field in a form?  I also want to use the tab, but the enter key would be nice too.

FYI - I do have several textareas and I need to use the enter key for returns when they type.  Will this be a conflict?

Thank you.
Erik

Comment: That would be really unintuitive, since for textareas, a newline can be entered as well

Comment: Can you? Yes. Should you? No. Messing with default browser behavior is bad form. The browser trains a user that this does this and that does that - at least for me, if you stray from that, that web page irritates me.

Comment: +1 for a genial idea. Yes, it's not intuitive, but I caught my self hitting enter on an not fulfilled form. Now, rethinking about your question, having seen my focus on a forgotten input is TOTALLY A GREAT IDEA. (not to talk that hitting enter after all (if all inputs entered) it will submit the form!) +100

Comment: It is possible but don't do that. The TAB Key is meant for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you were to add a class called 'TabOnEnter' to the fields where you want to cycle on enter.

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".TabOnEnter" , function(e)
  {
    //Only do something when the user presses enter
    if( e.keyCode ==  13 )
    {
       var nextElement = $('[tabindex="' + (this.tabIndex+1)  + '"]');
       console.log( this , nextElement ); 
       if(nextElement.length )
         nextElement.focus()
       else
         $('[tabindex="1"]').focus();  
    }   
  });

//Hidden inputs should get their tabindex fixed, not in scope ;)
//$(function(){ $('input[tabindex="4"]').fadeOut();  })
```

Not as cute as the previous answer, but it works now :

http://jsfiddle.net/konijn_gmail_com/WvHKA/

This way you use a standard HTML feature ( tabindex ) to determine the cycling order. Hidden elements should have their tabindex removed.

Comment: +1. I like the class idea, and the content of the function shows the general principle, but a real-world solution would likely need to figure out what the next editable element is rather than just using `.next()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn The real world solution would have to set the tabindex for each input element I guess.

Comment: this method cycles through text inputs only, how about textarea ? And one more thing: if one of the inputs have style="display:none;", then Enter key stop functioning on text input before the one with display:none; !

Comment: @armen, whatever puts the input hidden should also remove the tabindex. Cycling over text area's though is a good idea, I added it.

Comment: there is still a little problem with textarea, since when it has the focus, enter key must create new line, but not jump to next element. Also, this method cant work for me, since half form elements are "static", and the other half are rendered by an ajax call, different number of input elements depending on circumstance, putting elements randomly on different places of the form, so there is no "continuity" for them, thus cant tell ajax to return those elements tab-indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark (assuming your textareas are lined up):

```
$(".myTextareas").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $(this).next('.myTextareas').focus();
    }
});
```